# Where do I add Distinct Clause

Tags: sql, distinct

I have an SQL Query that searches a database and displays three columns: Date, Dataset, & Media.  For a query like this that searches a specific dataset, there are hundreds of the same media that fall under this dataset.  But I am only interested in seeing the media once.

This is my query right now:

```
  SELECT 
  DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
  SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) [Date],
  [Object] AS [Dataset],
  SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) AS [Media]
  FROM (Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date], 
  [Object],
  MsgId,
  Parms
  FROM JnlDataSection) A
  Where MsgID = '325' AND
  [Object] = 'UAT_sbusvrwm553 - INCR'
  Order By Date DESC;
```

### This gives me this output:

DATASET:

UAT

UAT

UAT

UAT

MEDIA:

V40555

V40555

V40555

V40001

### WHERE AS THE REQUIRED OUTPUT IS:

DATASET:

UAT

UAT

UAT

UAT

MEDIA:

V40555

V40001

V40002

V40003

I know I have to put a distinct clause somewhere I'm just not quite sure where.  Please Note I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Comment: Err, what's up with the date math/string manipulation?  Is `[Date]` not a DB 'date' (really timestamp) type?  Doing this will destroy the ability of the optimizer to use an index for the `ORDER BY` (which may not be important if the result set is small).  As a final note... Unless you have additional rows for example output, your desired output won't happen, as `DISTINCT` only operates on rows that are present (ie it can't auto-number for you).

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT goes immediately after SELECT.

Your query will look like

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD ...
```

Comment: add the distinct also in the inner select, the one where you have FROM (Select CONVERT ...

Comment: I did that as well.. Still same problem.

Comment: maybe the [date] column differs. Your expected output shows 2 columns (dataset and media) while you select 3 (date, dataset, media). Try the following: SELECT DISTINCT dataset, media FROM (all your SQL query goes here); Basically use another select on top of your current query

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant in my last comment above. It will definitely work

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Dataset], [Media]
FROM (  
SELECT 
  DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
  SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) [Date],
  [Object] AS [Dataset],
  SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) AS [Media]
  FROM (Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date], 
  [Object],
  MsgId,
  Parms
  FROM JnlDataSection) A
  Where MsgID = '325' AND
  [Object] = 'UAT_sbusvrwm553 - INCR'
  Order By Date DESC
);
```

Comment: That's the first suggestion you had with one distinct.  I'll try it again though.

Comment: please look careful at the code. I've wrapped everything in a new select, which takes only two columns instead of 3.

Comment: You really should have edited your previous answer, instead of making a new one).